# Apache Thrift Highlighting/auto complete

Tags: thrift

Is there a tool for editing thrift IDL that provide nice highlighting and/or auto complete? I was pleasantly surprised to find Erlang highlighting in Gedit recently, I am hoping something similar exists for Thrift IDL.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for Eclipse, I have used it several times. It only provides syntax highlighting and folding, auto complete is not supporting. You can get it from: http://thrift4eclipse.sourceforge.net/en/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

There's a GEdit language definition file for Thrift here:

https://github.com/RandyAbernethy/ThriftBook/tree/master/tools